# cs50 pset1 credit why use modulo?

Tags: c, modulo, cs50

I'm trying to solve cs50 pset1 with credit cart validation.

According to it, we need to multiply every alternate digit by 2 and then sum all the digits. The number is invalid if the last digit of the sum is zero.

The question mentions using using modulo, but I'm not sure if I understand it correctly.

It's suggested to use modulo to find the last digit of the number. I'm not sure what modulo is supposed to do. For example, it says for 4003600000000014 the number is 4. I suppose I have to check every digit until I find the modulo result.

But the credit cart number can have one or more of digits. So we can't use modulo for finding the last digit. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please don't make us watch a youtube video just to understand what you are asking. Please provide enough info in the question itself for us to be able to understand your problem and question.

Comment: You might consult your C textbook again and check what the module operator does. It does not search for any digits in a larger number. For any positive number `n` you can get the last digit by using `n%10`. No matter what digit this is and how many times this digit is present in the number.

Comment: @kaylum sorry. It's changed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am in the Credit question too but with a different issue.
I believe the `modulo` function is used to extract each digit in a number from right to left. You would have to loop over it (length of number) the number of times after which the last execution of the loop will give you the first digit(left most)

The loop would essentially contain:

- Runs the same amount of times as its length.
- `Digit=num%10`
- `num=num/10`  //To throwaway the right most digit so the next run the new digit will be extracted

At the end, digit will be equal to the left most digit.

This will work fo VISA Cards as only the first digit is required. But for the others like AMEX, you'll have to include an if statement to pullout the second digit as well in the run before the last.

Hope this helps!